# Verify maximal diameter of a tree in Dafny

Tags: proof-techniques, recursion

I am trying to learn formal methods and have been learning Dafny and practicing by verifying Leetcode problems.

I have gotten stuck on this one. https://leetcode.com/problems/diameter-of-binary-tree/description/

I have been able to verify that my algorithm creates a solution and satisfies the property that there exists a path and it is the width of a tree diameter (defined as the longest path between two nodes within the tree). However, I have not been able to figure out how to structure the proof that the diameter is the longest possible path within the tree.

I found this video formulating one proof of the problem, but's not really clear to me how to translate it to Dafny. Specifically it depends on using Dijkstras algorithm which is even more work to verify.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PFl93WM_ao

I have had a hard time getting my head around how to handle describing
all tree paths in Dafny. The set of paths are finite in a finite tree, but
Dafny doesn't believe it because of it's own heuristics. I realize that I don't
need to convince Dafny that it is true. I can define the set of all
possible paths as an `iset` (infinite set).

Then the difficulty becomes, how do I
convince Dafny that only certain types of paths exist, and those are
all of the types of paths, Also paths are unique, but they can also be
reversed once. Do I even need to prove those things?

I have been able to show something about paths which include the root of the tree. However, I have not yet figure out how to say much about paths which do not include the root. https://github.com/hath995/dafny/blob/main/leetcode/DiameterOfBinaryTree.min.dfy#L314

```
// original algorithm that solves leetcode.
function diameter(node: TreeNode | null): [number, number] {
  if(node == null) {
    return [-1,-1];
  }
  if(node.left == null && node.right == null) {
    return [0, 0];
  }
  let leftDiameter = diameter(node.left);
  let rightDiameter = diameter(node.right);
  let height = Math.max(leftDiameter[0],rightDiameter[0]) + 1;
  let dim = leftDiameter[0]+rightDiameter[0]+2;
  let maxDiameter = Math.max(leftDiameter[1], rightDiameter[1], dim);
  return [height, maxDiameter];
}

function diameterOfBinaryTree(root: TreeNode | null): number {
  return diameter(root)[1];
};
```

Current verification of that code. https://github.com/hath995/dafny/blob/main/leetcode/DiameterOfBinaryTree.min.dfy#L746

Data types and predicates

https://github.com/hath995/dafny/blob/main/lib/binaryTree.dfy#L7